# The Bean Machine Function - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

The bean machine, also known as a quincunx or the Galton box, is a device for statistics experiments named after English scientist Sir Francis Galton. It consists of an upright board with evenly spaced nails (or pegs) in a triangular form:

See Figures Below for General Idea

[image]

I am having trouble coming up with a method that will print out a histogram for (the buildup of beans), given a list with the number of beans in each column.

`end_location = [1, 0, 3, 5, 7, 0, 0, 3]`

Note that the `end_location` list may not always be 8 columns, it will vary, so it would be fantastic if the method did not rely on there only being 8 columns.  A possible way to get around this could be something like `num_column = len(end_location)`, which would assign the number of columns needed to `num_column` variable.

In the end, something like this should be outputted (returned or printed, preferably returned):

`end_location = [1, 0, 3, 5, 7, 0, 0, 3]`

```
    0 
    0
   00
   00  
  000  0  
  000  0
0 000  0
```

There is one bean in the first location, 0 in the second, three in the third, five in the fourth, 7 in the fifth, etc...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this:

```
end_location = [1, 0, 3, 5, 7, 0, 0, 3]
```

There will be at most `max(end_location)` rows.

Each row can be computed via:

```
''.join('0' if x >= v else ' ' for x in end_location)
```

Where `v` is from `max(end_location)` to `1`.

So the code to print the rows would be:

```
>>> end_location = [1, 0, 3, 5, 7, 0, 0, 3]
>>> for v in reversed(range(1, max(end_location)+1)):
...     print(''.join('0' if x >= v else ' ' for x in end_location))
... 
    0   
    0   
   00   
   00   
  000  0
  000  0
0 000  0
```